# Webpack 4 dynamic and on demand import

Tags: webpack

Is it possible with webpack to make an import on demand AND with a dynamic name? For example, if I have such a piece of code

`./src/index.js`

```js
function start() {
  const files = ['./foo.js'];
  const s = import(files[0]);
  console.log(new s());
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = start;
```

`./src/foo.js`

```js
export class Foo {}
```

`index.html`

```html
<body>
  <button id="button">Click</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
</body>
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    foo: './src/foo.js'
  }
}
```

When I run this code, after I click my button, I have the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './foo.js'
>       at eval (eval at ./src lazy recursive (index.js:96), :5:11)
>   (anonymous) @ src lazy namespace object?4252:5
>   Promise.then (async)
>   start @ index.js?b635:4

I also tried with `const files = ['./src/foo.js'];` but same.

The question is, is it possible to achieve this dynamic on-demand import with webpack 4?

Answer (score 0):

It is called ["Code splitting with dynamic context"](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/code-splitting-native-import-context). The way that import is going to work with webpack is that, these on demand required chunks are going to be "autoload" by webpack on demand, only when required.

The point is, as @Batista has pointed out, this import has a result a promise, which is wrapped into a default property, so you could:

```
async function start() {
  const files = ['./foo.js'];
  const s = await import(files[0]);
  console.log(new s.default());
}
```

By doing this, you don't need to add this to entrypoints, the only caveat is that is does not generates a bundle with a "fixed" name, to generate names, you could add:

```
...
import(/* webpackChunkName: "mychunk" */ files[0])
...
```

You don't need to manually add those to your webpack, these are going to be loaded by webpack.

Comment: It doesn't work either, same error as above. I found the solution though, you can check my answer below @matheus-silva

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `` import(`${files[0}`) `` with the backtick (template literal syntax). Using `import(files[0])` doesn't work, even though `files[0]` is a string.

Not sure why though, if anyone as the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the promise instead?

```
import("module/foo").then(foo => console.log(foo.default))
```

Comment: the name inside the `import` comes from a variable `import(files[0])`. Of course if I do `import('./foo')`, it works but here this is not what I want.